# Logging fails if program stopped using ctrl + c

Tags: c, file

I have written a C program in which I am logging the results to a file. There is an infinite while loop - this is a requirement. To debug the code, I need to look at the log file, but as the program is running, I don't see anything written there. Closing the program forcibly using ctrl+C does not help either. I see nothing written on the file.

I am using simple fopen and fprintf functions to read the file in write mode and write to it.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "this wants itself to be written the moment this statement is executed\n");
```

PS: There is no bug in the code. If I put a terminating condition in while loop and program exits gracefully, I do see things written in the log file.

Comment: You have heard about [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)?

Comment: You could also catch the `CTRL-C` "signal" (how to do that is platform dependent) and gracefully exit.

Comment: `setvbuf(fp,NULL,_IOLBF,0)` after the `fopen` will put you in line buffered mode. This mode will cause your output to go to the file after the `\n` in your fprintf.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that would be ideal for me. I am on GCC 4.1.2

Comment: Thanks @evaitl. This works. You can write this as the answer,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A difference between printing to a console and printing to a file is that streams are line buffered by default when attached to the console, but block buffered when attached to a file. Change your code to:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "w");
setvbuf(fp,0,_IOLBF,0);
fprintf(fp, "this wants itself to be written the moment this statement is executed\n");
```

and your output will be line buffered even though the stream is attached to a file. You can also do [unbuffered](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) streams.

[EDIT: ]

Ref C11 7.21.5.6:

> Synopsis

```
#include <stdio.h>
int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
            char * restrict buf,
            int mode, size_t size);
```

> Description
>
> The setvbuf function may be used only after the stream pointed to by
>   stream has been associated with an open file and before any other
>   operation (other than an unsuccessful call to setvbuf) is performed on
>   the stream. The argument mode determines how stream will be buffered,
>   as follows: _IOFBF causes input/output to be fully buffered; _IOLBF
>   causes input/output to be line buffered; _IONBF causes input/output to
>   be unbuffered. If buf is not a null pointer, the array it points to
>   may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the setvbuf function 
>   and the argument size specifies the size of the array; otherwise, size
>   may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the setvbuf function.
>   The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.
>
> Returns
>
> The setvbuf function returns zero on success, or nonzero if an invalid
>   value is given for mode or if the request cannot be honored.

Comment: Streams that communicate with a console are *also* usually buffered (the exception being `stderr`). It's just that *requesting input from an interactive stream* is one of the triggers for flushing line-buffered output-streams.

Comment: I said `line buffered`, not that they are not buffered. The `\n` is sufficient to flush a line buffered stream.

Comment: Yes, `'\n'` is sufficient to flush a line-buffered output-stream, *but so is reading input from an interactive stream*. This I would consider the bigger difference between file I/O and interactive I/O.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to change, but my feelings won't be hurt if you want to edit.

Comment: Does that work for all compilers?  Or is it specific to GCC?  If _IOLBF isn't  really portable could you list the compilers for which it works?

Comment: Ref: C11 7.21.5.6. Also C89 and C99.

Answer (score -2):

You should to see the the function fopen(),if you fopen a file with "w" mode,it means if this file exist,clear this file and then write.I think you should use "a+" mode to append data in the end.